# List of questions layout

Tags: support, questions, homepage

Actually there are two related questions. I searched on meta and on my profile page, but could not find an answer to my questsions.

On SO there are two pages that list questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/ (Interesting, Featured, Hot, Week, Month)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions (Newest, Featured, Frequent, Votes, Active, Unanswered)

They have basically the same functionality (to list questions) but have a different layout. And although the have a different layout, the provide almost the same information for each question.

My Questions:

- Why are there two different layouts for the "same" data?
- Is there a way to change the layout of either page to match the layout of the other page?

Comment: I suppose the landing page is for new or irregular users & the other (/questions) for regulars.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil no, it's always "interesting" tab.

Answer (score 3):

The homepage https://stackoverflow.com/ display a set of 90 "interesting" questions, which is **user customized** (different for each user), using a special forumula based on the user favorite tags, ignored tags, views and more. It's explained in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) which also contains the full formula.

The full questions page https://stackoverflow.com/questions show **all** questions (with paging of course) and is the same for all users.

As for different layout, the homepage of all sites has that "minimal" layout e.g. showing only user names without their profile pictures, most likely to save bandwidth. Major part of the visitors only view the homepage, if the profile pictures would be served there is means lots of extra GB in bandwidth.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about the customization of the "interesting" tab. Thanks.

Comment: But that does not explain why they look different. Both are ordered lists of elements from the same group, yet one displays votes/answers/views vertically and other horizontally. Doesn't make too much sense, when I think about it.

Comment: @Mołot different views, added my assumption in an edit.

Comment: "if the profile pictures would be served there is means lots of extra GB in bandwidth." - but it's imgur bandwidth, not SE :P

Comment: @Mołot true, but it will also slow down the load times which are now super fast.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Would like to see it officially confirmed or denied. Makes sense, but it does not mean it's true.